# Nested AJAX with different input speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i had this ajax  question during a job interview:

we have this code where onChange makes an AJAX call ( to asdf server ) which also makes another AJAX call ( to qwer server ),

```
 function onDescription(description) {
    var content = $('').text(description);
    $('#results').append(content);
}

    function onSearchResults(searchResults){
        $('#results').html('');
        $.each(searchResults, function(result){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://qwer.com/describe',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: result,
                success: onDescription
            });
        });
    }

    function onChange(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'http:://asdf.com/search',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#search').val(),
            success: onSearchResults
        });
    }

$('#search').keydown(onChange);
```

the question is: what will happen if the user inputs text in different speed.

1- asdf server will be overloaded 
2- the description from qwer will not be displayed when the user inputs text very quickly 
3- the results of the previews search will be displayed instead of the current 
4- descriptions from qwer for the current search query are displayed before the request to asdf

for me even the choices are not very clear.
so in your opinion what will happen if we have a nested AJAX call and different inputs speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the above. AJAX is designed to not be deterministic. If a user starts typing "moon", four requests will be sent to asdf: "m", "mo", "moo", and "moon". But the order that the results come back is nondeterministic. The server could take a different amount of time to respond to each request. You could get responses in the order "moo", "m", "moon", "mo". With varying typing speed, the results could change, but *it depends*.

The safe thing to do is ignore the results for previous queries. Here's a quick fix:

```
function onDescription(description) {
    var content = $('').text(description);
    $('#results').append(content);
}

var searchResultQuery = '';
function onSearchResults(query){
    searchResultQuery = query;
    return (function(query) {
        return function(searchResults) {
            if (query != searchResultQuery) {
                return;
            }
            $('#results').html('');
            $.each(searchResults, function(result){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://qwer.com/describe',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: result,
                    success: onDescription
                });
            });
        };
    })(query);
}

function onChange(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'http:://asdf.com/search',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#search').val(),
        success: onSearchResults($('#search').val())
    });
}

$('#search').keydown(onChange);
```